# Post from Flash to PHP in Facebook app

Tags: php, actionscript, actionscript-2, facebook

I published 2 days ago a Facebook app, it's a flash game, after the game over, the flash file POST score to my php file, Publish your score to wall if you beat your highscore, Facebook disabled the application because bad reviews from users.

How to POST from Falsh to PHP without redirecting the user, i want after the game over POST score, insert it in DB, and show the user Stream Publish popup if he want to publish to wall the score or not.

The flash game is developped by Adobe Flash CS3, AS2.

Any idea please,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data back to your server, you can write:

```
var sender = new LoadVars();

sender.x = "xxx";

sender.y = "yyy";

sender.z = "zzz";

sender.send("http://www.yourdomain.com/yourscript.php", "", "post")
```

To sendAndLoad

In case you want to get back data at the same time you send your data back to the server, you can use the sendAndLoad api:

```
var loader = new LoadVars();

loader.onLoad = function(success) {

  if(success) {

    // read your data here, e.g.

    trace(this.x); // suppose the server send back a variable x

    trace(this.y); // and a variable y

  }

}

var sender = new LoadVars();

sender.x = "xxx";

sender.sendAndLoad("http://www.yourdomain.com/yourscript.php", loader, "post");
```

Comment: IF that didn't help the asker, it sure helped me!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple.  Some example code here:
http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/566

Comment: yes, the application is posting data from flash to PHP, but what i want is to POST without redirecting the action link, for example use Ajax or something like that with Facebook canvas app.

Comment: You aren't making sense.  Are you posting with Flash, or are you posting with Javascript?  If it is Flash, then follow the code on that page.  AJAX has NOTHING to do with Flash.